# Constructing gtools and ftools ado packages remotely with no internet, encountering error r(111)

Tags: stata

I'm trying to remotely construct gtools and ftools on a computer that has no internet access with the help of an on-site research assistant. A bit of a logistical nightmare.

The Microsoft computer has run gtools/ftools commands before, but Stata was recently upgraded to Stata 18 from 17, and the ado directories were replaced.

My problem is that on many of the gtools subcommands, like "fasterxtile" and "gegen" and "gduplicates", I keep on getting the error r(111).

This is the error that pops up for "variable does not exist" or "ambiguous abbreviation". I know for a fact that the variables I am referring to DO exist and are NOT ambiguously abbreviated (I have set varabbrev off).

I have tried installing ftools and gtools locally and transferring over the ado/mlib/plugin files to the local ado folder, and I have run mata: mata mlib index

But I keep on getting this error r(111).

For instance, I have id variables (I have an id-time panel), and just to check the syntax, I have run

```
gduplicates drop id, force  

bys id: gegen check = mean(id)
```

[Here](https://imgur.com/a/k1pYvcr) you can find images of me running "gduplicates drop" with and without trace on.

And both of these commands output r(111).

Does anyone have any advice? Are there likely ado/mlib packages that I am missing?

I am VERY desperate at this point.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.reddit.com/r/stata/comments/15eq45i/constructing_gtools_and_ftools_ado_packages/ and https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1722393-constructing-gtools-and-ftools-ado-packages-remotely-with-no-internet-and-continuously-encountering-error-r-111  Telling people about cross-posting is (1) a rule on Reddit (2) a request on Statalist (3) a good idea on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Despite your best endeavours, I can't see here a reproducible problem.